# Adding to a list in java

Tags: java, list

I'm using List of strings and trying to insert strings to specified indices using

```
lst.add(index, string);
(lst is of type `List`).
```

First I initiated the list to 20 spots of null (now `lst.size() = 20`).
When I'm inserting the first string it's all good : `lst.add(1,"Hi")` and the list: 
`[null,Hi,null,...null]`,  `lst.size()` is still 20

But when I try to add the next strings it extends the list. I mean if I use lst.add`(0,"Bye")` the list looks like this: `[Bye,null,Hi,null,null,...null]` and `lst.size() = 21` ! Why ?
it added the string "Bye" before the null though it should have replaced it

Any help ? thanks :)

Comment: You are doing it wrong, but still it's interesting question.

Comment: Yet another example of why we need upvote privileges restricted.

Comment: To the OP (And anyone upvoting this) ... **because that's exactly what the documentation says will happen**. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(int,%20E). Upvoting "I didn't read the Javadoc" does not benefit anyone.

Comment: I don't know what's a java doc .. Do you know any other method of list that inserts without expending the list ?

Answer (score 4):

The `add()` method **inserts** into the list.

From JavaDoc:

> Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list
>   (optional operation). Shifts the element currently at that position
>   (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their
>   indices).

You want to use the `set()` method instead.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that thanks. but I still have to use list, is there any method for that ?

Comment: As I said, use the `set` method in the same way as you were using `add`. e.g. `lst.set(1,"Hi")` will **overwrite** the element in that position without increasing the size of the list.

Answer (score 0):

When you do 'add' it is actually an insert to a list - therefore you would have 21 elements instead of 20 after the add.

A list can be thought as a resizeable array. You shouldn't need to initialise an array with 20 nulls inserted in it.

If you want total control on the size of the collection, simply use array instead of list (`String[]` instead of `List<String>`)